# Nginx return takes prescedence over deny?

Tags: nginx

I'm seeing this behavior in Nginx 1.4.6. When I have a `deny` clause, `return` will override it. I set up this trivial example:

```
server {
    deny all;
    location = /test {
        return 200;
    }
}
```

It returns 200.

I'm looking for (and expecting) the oposite behavior—for `deny` to take precedence. I considered `if (...) { return 200; }`, but I'm not sure what to test for in the `if`. `deny` works as expected if nginx tries to serve a *file* rather than just return.

Comment: That's because nginx process request in phases, and rewrite phase (where `return` belongs) goes before access phase (where `deny` works). http://www.nginxguts.com/2011/01/phases/

Comment: BTW, `if` is also processed in rewrite phase, so it will not work. Why is it a problem?

Comment: @AlexeyTen Ah. So is there another way to serve an empty response after access? The obvious one is actually serve an empty file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have [Echo](https://github.com/openresty/echo-nginx-module) module. It's compiled in Debian/Ubuntu builds by default. In that case you could use `echo -n "";` instead of `return 200;`.

If you want “pure” solution without third party module, you could use `proxy_pass`:

```
location /test {
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:11111;
}

...

server {
  listen 127.0.0.1:11111;
  return 200;
}
```

or `try_files`:

```
location /test {
  try_files FAKE_NON_EXISTENT @return200;
}

location @return200 {
  return 200;
}
```